# Propagate a Select with angularJS and read the option

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem to read the information selected that is propagate in a select.

```
<div ng-show="deviceDetail != null" ng-model="example" >
    <select >
        <option value="NONE">Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="option in deviceDetail" ng-change="selectOption()">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    The value of the selection is: {{example}}
  </div>
```

this is the HTML code and in the `{{example}}` I want to see the information that the user selected.

this is the part of the js releted:

```
$scope.selectOption = function() {
        $scope.example = option.productName;
    };
```

How I can fix it?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Can you give the array of deviceDetail??

Comment: @Reena I can't, It is coming from a ajax call but this is correct the only problem is that I can't put the value that you selected in other variable :(

Comment: does deviceDetail contain the property productName??

Comment: Can u copy and post the list of deviceList from console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `example` scope variable directly in `<select>` instead calling `ng-change` event and assigning into that function.

You can directly set **option.name** to **example** model with the use of ng-options too.

Here You have applied `ng-model` directive to `div` tag.

`<div>` is not input element so apply `ng-model` to `<select>` element here.

I would suggest to use `ng-options` directive for filling the selection list in `<select>`. `ng-repeat` is also fine.

Here you are binging `ng-change` event so in the function if requires then you can pass the object on which event is triggering so you can use that object or perform any operation on that.

Below is the modified template.

```
<div ng-show="deviceDetail != null">
    <select >
        <option value="NONE">Select</option>
        <option ng-model="example" ng-options="option in deviceDetail" ng-change="selectOption(option)">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    The value of the selection is: {{example}}
</div>
```

Comment: @David_Garcia Let me know if still you face any difficulties to understand what I said. If necessary I can provide one demo fiddle or plnkr.

Answer (score 1):

You should to pass current option:

```
<select >
        <option value="NONE">Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="option in deviceDetail" ng-change="selectOption(option )">{{option}}</option>
    </select>

$scope.selectOption = function(option) {
        $scope.example = option; // is there property .productName?;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div ng-show="deviceDetail != null">
  <select >
    <option value="NONE">Select</option>
    <option ng-model="option" ng-options="option in deviceDetail" ng-change="selectOption(option)">
    {{option}}</option>
</select>
<br/>
   The value of the selection is: {{example}}
```

Js:

```
         $scope.selectOption = function(option) {
         $scope.example = option;
       };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ng-options`
    
      
      
      The value of the selection is: {{example}}